# How to update data on swift immediately

Tags: swift, uitableview, reload, alamofire

I'd like to update likeNum data on swift immediately after a like button is pressed. At the following tapLike function, I've updated the likeNum data at server side (written by rails), then reload data by self.tableView.reloadData(). However, it cannot update the shown data simultaneously. Could you tell me how to update data at immediately?

```
func tapLike(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        var userId = self.defaults.objectForKey("uid") as! Int
        let parameters = [
            "id": recognizer.view!.tag,
            "user_id": userId
        ]

        Alamofire.request(.POST, uri.answersApi + "/like", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
            .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("qaIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QATableViewCell
    cell.likeNum.text = String(answers[indexPath.row].likeNum!)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've found another big problem. The reason is I've not reload the data from server side to the model at client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UI` should only be updated from `main thread`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thx Kheni! I'll try it!